# Exclude some rows from having condition

Tags: mysql

How can I exclude rows with `show_all = '1'` from HAVING clause?

```sql
SELECT 
   ID,
   ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('". $lat ."') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('". $long ."') ) + sin( radians('". $lat ."') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM events 
WHERE active = '1' 
  AND closed = '0' 
  AND category IN ( '" . implode( "', '" , $styleArr ) . "' ) 
HAVING distance < 1000 AND distance > 0 
ORDER BY events.start_date DESC
```

I don't want to apply HAVING condition if row's `show_all = '1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the HAVING clause to this:

```
HAVING (distance < 1000 AND distance > 0) OR show_all = '1'
```